# Iterate through a dictionary and return keys and values that share x amount of values? x is user input?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, cluster-analysis

> Given a file named hobbies.txt.
>
> This file contains a group of Facebook users and their hobbies.
>
> Each line in the file contains a user/username and a list of hobbies
>   of that user. The data in each line is delimited by commas.
>
> For instance in the line: `2254,reading,coding,swimming,playing soccer,`
>
> The user/username is: 2254
>
> The hobbies are: reading`, coding, swimming, and playing soccer
>
> The number and type of hobbies may differ from one user to another.
>
> This file will be your data set that your code has to read to be able
>   to implement  a code that does the following:
>
> Finding circles/networks of friends:
>
> In each circle you will report, all the users should share at least x
>   number of hobbies
>
> x is a variable that a user can input to the program.
>
> Circles of friends should be written to a file named circles.txt.
>
> Each line should have the usernames in the circle/network you found,
>   tab character, and list of shared hobbies.
>
> for example, a line may look like:
>   `2254,552,1258    reading,swimming,hiking`
>
> Finding popular users:
>
> Popularity is based on being part of at least y circles/networks.
>
> y can be variable that a user can input to the program.
>
> Popular users should be written to a file named popular.txt.  Each
>   user and how many circles/networks the user belongs to, should be in
>   separate line and separated by the tab character.
>
> For instance: `2254   5`
>
> This step should occur after step (a.).
>
> Hint:  You may want to save the circles you found in part (a.) in some
>   data structure so that you can us them in this part.

My Code: python

```
import csv
csv_file = open ('hobbies.txt')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
csv_dict={}
for row in csv_reader:
  k= row[0]
  v = row[1:]
  csv_dict[k] = [x.strip() for x in v]

for i in csv_dict.values():
  i.pop()

keyList =[*csv_dict]
circle ={}  
for i in range(len(keyList)):
   i_item = keyList[i]
   for j in range(i+1, len(keyList)):
      j_item = keyList[j]
      user1 = set(csv_dict[i_item])
      user2 = set(csv_dict[j_item])
      hob = user1.intersection(user2)
      if (len(hob) > 1):
      hob = tuple(hob)
      circle[hob] = [i_item, j_item]    
print(circle)
```

---

```
output: 
{('cosplay', 'textiles'): ['2345', '4545'], ('orienteering', 'running'): 
['4567', '5050'], ('orienteering', 'jumping', 'running'): ['8888', '5050'], 
('dancing', 'singing'): ['9999', '1010'], ('cake', 'racing', 'decorating', 
'car'): ['4545', '5050']}
```

Right now my code is only comparing between two users, how can I compare for maybe 3, 4, 5, ......, n that share x hobbies?

Comment: You can build up a dictionary of user and a set of hobbies by parsing your file (*You have this already*). From here, you can make a dictionary of hobbies to a set of users who share them. Using this, you can make a dictionary of hobbies to count of users for ease of lookup.

Comment: Is storing in a dict the best way to go? I'm thinking maybe store the hobbies in bits. then you can simply use a bitwise AND to compare 2 people and every over lapping combination will have a unique value.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule that is what my code is currently doing. I cant seem to compare multiple users. I set the hobbies as keys and the users as values. Iam pretty new to python and data analysis. So i have no idea how to make it work with bitwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary of hobbies to a set of users who share them.

Say `hobby_users`. Use this to make a dictionary of hobbies to number of users who share them (`hobby_user_count`).

```
user_hobbies = defaultdict(set)
all_hobbies = set()

for row in csv_reader:
    user, hobbies = row[0], [h.strip() for h in row[1:]]
    user_hobbies[user].update(hobbies)
    all_hobbies.update(hobbies) # build set of hobbies to be used later

hobby_users = {
    h: set(u for u, hs in user_hobbies.items() if h in hs) for h in all_hobbies
}

hobby_user_count = {
    h: len(us) for h, us in hobby_users.items()
} # if you have hobby_users or

hobby_user_count = {
    h: sum(1 for hs in user_hobbies.values() if h in hs) for h in all_hobbies
} # just using all hobbies
```

You can look up `hobby_user_count` for the user input.

```
shared_hobbies_matching_count = [
    h for h, user_count in hobby_user_count.items() if user_count is user_input
]
```